# In-call status bar enforces a black bar - iOS

Tags: ios, uistatusbar, in-call

When the viewcontroller overrides `prefersStatusBarHidden` and is set to be `true`. When there is a in-call status bar, there is a black bar on the top. Is there way to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by auto layout. Please make constraints with view(not top layout guide). This maybe help.